# Trying to code sigma notation and not really sure what to do

Tags: python, formula

I have been trying to create the code for a homework assignment and have had no success.

Essentially we have to encode the following formula into python;

Equation to be encoded

[image]

I've tried messing about with the sum() function and have checked other threads with more complicated examples although these haven't been of much help.

```
 #x=sum(1/2^k)for krange(1,int(input())
 #k=range(1,(int(input('Enter N:'))))
 #for k in range(1,3,1):
 num_range=list(range(1,3,1))#
 total=0
 for i in num_range:
 total +=i
 total
 sum(num_range)
 print(sum(num_range))



 #k=list(1,3)
 #x=1/pow(2,k)
 #sum(x)
 #print(sum(x))
 #x=sum(k)

 #k=range(1,3)
 #x=sum(1/pow(2,k))
 #sum(x)
 #print(x)



 #sum+=([1/2**k])
 #print(sum(1/pow(2,k)))'
```

Comment: Can you define (ideally with code) the simplest possible example of the problem you are trying to solve? If in doubt, re read your question, imagine you're someone who is not familiar with any of the course material you have seen

Comment: what have you got so far?

Comment: The equation is; 1/2**k where k is the range from one to N which is to be input by the user

Comment: Here is one of my attempts so far, I've been relying on google searches and its a bit of a mess; 
#x=sum(1/2^k)for krange(1,int(input())
#k=range(1,(int(input('Enter N:'))))
#for k in range(1,3,1):
num_range=list(range(1,3,1))#
total=0
for i in num_range:
    total +=i
    total
sum(num_range)
print(sum(num_range))



#k=list(1,3)
#x=1/pow(2,k)
#sum(x)
#print(sum(x))
#x=sum(k)

#k=range(1,3)
#x=sum(1/pow(2,k))
#sum(x)
#print(x)

#sum+=([1/2**k])
#print(sum(1/pow(2,k)))

Comment: @Matt Hello Matt, please edit your post and paste your code, it will be easier to read. Cheers

Comment: @Matt improve your indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's builtin sum method, and a generator expression:

```
def series_sum(N):
    return sum(1.0 / 2**k for k in range(1, N + 1))
```

This works as follows:

- `range(1, N + 1)` produces an *iterable* whose elements are the values 1, 2, ..., N sequentially.
  Reference:  [builtin range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).
- `1.0 / 2**k for k in range(1, N + 1)` produces a new iterable that transforms this into 1/2, 1/4, ..., 1/(2^N).
  Reference:  [generator
  expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions).
- `sum(...)` computes the sum of all the elements of the iterable that it is passed.
  Reference:  [builtin `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).

The nice thing about Python is that if you read the code out loud, you would say something very similar to the words you would say while reading the mathematical expression.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much. I'm seriously considering purchasing a book for python. Do you have any recommendations?